# Grant Permission to external user in azure active directory to access sharepoint site

Tags: azure, permissions, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps, sql-grant

I have developed a logic app, which receives a post request with JSON Object and I create external user in azure active directory. Till here everything is fine. Now I want to grant permission to newly created user to access our sharepoint site. There is a solution using Plumsail action connector but I do not want to use it. I want to achieve this using microsoft graph api.

Can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: to grant permission to newly created user, does it mean i have to add that user in office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I think is adding the user to a group (with the AD connector) or using dynamic group to pick up the user. Then you can have sharepoint license connected to the group and have sharepoint access on the group.